# change default placeholder area of date input field to text "Date" if no date selected

Tags: html, css

I want to change default dd-mm-yyyy field of date type input to this one

[image]

I tried assigning input value to Date but it didn't work

```
<span className="right-element"><input  type="date" name="leadDate" value ="Date" /></span>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this to get placeholder to be 'Date' -

```
<input placeholder="Date" type="text" onfocus="(this.type='date')" />
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  <input placeholder="Date" class="form-control" type="text" onfocus="(this.type='date')" onblur="(this.type='text')" id="date">
```